# Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP): Filter Group

Tags: account, contact, relationships, roll-up-summary, npsp

I'm attempting to create a rollup summary on the Account Object for related a field on related Contacts. I'm using [NPSP-Customizable Rollup-Filter Groups](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/opportunity-settings-in-nonprofit-success-pack/enable-customizable-rollups-npsp). The end result will be the combined weights of species=dog on related contacts will appear in a field on the Account object.

**ISSUE:** In Filter Groups, I can't get it to show the "Species" field. In fact, (as shown below), picking the Contact object only shows two available fields. What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Account Object.** 
[image]

**Contact Object.** 
[image]

**Filter Group Screen.** 
[image]

**Customizable Rollup in NPSP.** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPSP's Customizable Rollups feature is designed to facilitate complex, filtered rollups *of giving data*, from Opportunities and Payments, based upon hard or soft credit mechanics.

The feature doesn't provide fully generalized rollups of any object to any object.

You can read about the [types](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Hard-v-Soft-Cred-Rollups) of CRLPs that are available in NPSP documentation. You've selected an Opportunity Rollup based on Contact Soft Credit, which allows you to roll up Opportunity data based on soft credits to associated Contacts. It doesn't make other Contact fields available.

To achieve this objective, you'll need a different product, such as the open source Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries.